# When is $\mathbb{C}G \cong \mathbb{C}H$ for two groups $G \not \cong H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

When is $\mathbb{C}G \cong \mathbb{C}H$ as $\mathbb{C}$ algebras for groups $G$ and $H$? I am thinking about the finite case.

Of course, if $G \cong H$ as groups then $\mathbb{C}G \cong \mathbb{C}H$, but what if $G \not\cong H$?

Obviously, we must have $|G| = |H|$, and since for $\phi : \mathbb{C}G \to \mathbb{C}H$ to be an algebra isomorphism, we require $\phi(aa') = \phi(a) \phi(a')$ for all $a, a' \in \mathbb{C}G$, so we must also have $|Z(G)| = |Z(H)|$.

Are these conditions sufficient for $\mathbb{C}G \cong \mathbb{C}H$? If not, what are the sufficient conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are not sufficient.

For finite $G$, Wedderburn's theorem gives
$$
\mathbb{C}G\cong M_{n_1}(\mathbb{C})\times\dots\times M_{n_k}(\mathbb{C}).
$$
So $\mathbb{C}G\cong\mathbb{C}H$ if and only if $G$ and $H$ has the same irrep degrees $n_1,\dots,n_k$ (multiplicities included) over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Could you provide a specific example?

Comment: oh of course, can't believe I forgot Wedderburn, thank you

Comment: @lisyarus Surely the smallest pair of non-isomorphic groups of the same order will do? - both have 4 irreducible representations of degree 1.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Indeed, thank you!

Comment: I think your centre of $D_8$ is wrong.